# Converting Multiple Column values into Binary

Tags: r, dataframe

```
ID<-c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")  
x<-c(0,1,2,1,1)
y<-c(2,1,1,1,1)
z<-c(0,1,1,0,0)
mydata<-data.frame(ID,x,y,z)
```

How can I convert all the columns except ID column into binary, like above 0 should be coded as 1.

My original data has around 1000 columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
mydata[-1]  <- + (mydata[-1] > 0)
```

or

```
mydata[-1] <- 1 - !mydata[-1]
```

such that

```
> mydata
  ID x y z
1 A1 0 1 0
2 A2 1 1 1
3 A3 1 1 1
4 A4 1 1 0
5 A5 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can covert your values into logical, then convert to integer. Here I use `mutate` from the `dplyr` package.

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% mutate(across(-ID, ~as.integer(as.logical(.x))))  

ID x y z
1 A1 0 1 0
2 A2 1 1 1
3 A3 1 1 1
4 A4 1 1 0
5 A5 1 1 0
```

Comment: Great! `where(is.numeric)` is perfect here

Comment: @Hoel That should work too! But OP: *convert all the columns except ID column*, so I think stating `-ID` explicitly might be more appropriate :)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use `sign`:

```r
cbind(mydata[1], sign(mydata[-1]))
#  ID x y z
#1 A1 0 1 0
#2 A2 1 1 1
#3 A3 1 1 1
#4 A4 1 1 0
#5 A5 1 1 0
```